# Не происходит вывода в файл из командной строки

Tags: вывод, cmd, файлы, c++

Здравствуйте! Нужно написать программу, которая копирует вводимый с клавиатуры код (до эмулированного конца файла) в файл, имя которого будет передано в командной строке.

Но при вызове в командой строке (сначала пишу адрес программы, потом название файла), программа сразу пишет Output is complete, но вывода не происходит - файл ни создается, ни заменяется. Объясните пожалуйста, в чем проблема.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    using namespace std;
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        cout << "INVALID CMD ARGUMENTS.\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        char ch = '0';
        ofstream fout(argv[1]);
        cout << "Enter a text: " << endl;
        while (fout.is_open() && !cin.eof())
        {
            cin.get(ch);
            fout << ch;
        }
    }
    cout << "Output is complete!\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**Обновление**

Я ввожу текст, нажимаю `^Z, Enter, опять ^Z` (по другому не работает) и файл просто не создается. он пишет что Output is complete и всё.

И еще важное условие - без использования cmd все работает как надо.

**Обновление 2**

Вот мой вывод

```
C:\Users\Никита>D:\Dropbox\Pascal\C++\project1\Debug\project1.exe a.txt
argv[0]: D:\Dropbox\Pascal\C++\project1\Debug\project1.exe
argv[1]: a.txt
fout.is_open(): 1
Enter a text:
ABCDEFGH
125
^Z
Output is complete!
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
```

**Обновление 3**

a.txt не создается вообще

---

Важная поправка!
Если добавить это в конец (fin - обьект ifstream):

```
while(!fin.eof())
{
    fin >> ch;
    cout << ch
}
```

то выводит всё - будто все создалось.

Comment: Очевидно, программа не может открыть `fout`. Проверяйте до цикла и выводите сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: @dbs1024: Хм. Странно. А почему в цикл не входит? Неужели `cin.eof()` вернул `true`? Или в цикл таки входит?

Comment: @dbs1024: Ну, а вы пишете «сразу пишет Output is complete». Значит, не сразу? Опишите точно, что происходит.

Comment: @dbs1024: попробуйте проследить, какие символы (коды) приходят к вам в цикле.

Answer (score 2):

[[[[[[[[@dbs1024](/users/20373/dbs1024)](/users/20373/dbs1024)](/users/20373/dbs1024)](/users/20373/dbs1024)](/users/20373/dbs1024)](/users/20373/dbs1024)](/users/20373/dbs1024)](/users/20373/dbs1024), наверное как-то не так результат проверяете.

В принципе, этот код должен работать.

(Только лишний `\n` (точнее, последний введенный перед ^Z символ) запишется в выходной файл.

*Сами разберетесь, почему?*)

И зачем постоянно проверять `fout.is_open()` не понимаю. Боитесь, что что-то сломалось во время записи?

Тогда уж доводите до конца. Анализируйте после `while` и пишите диагностику.

**Обновление**

[[[[[[[[@dbs1024](/users/20373/dbs1024)](/users/20373/dbs1024)](/users/20373/dbs1024)](/users/20373/dbs1024)](/users/20373/dbs1024)](/users/20373/dbs1024)](/users/20373/dbs1024)](/users/20373/dbs1024), у меня (в Win XP MinGW)

```
C:\Documents and Settings\avp\src\hashcode>g++ c.cpp

C:\Documents and Settings\avp\src\hashcode>a
INVALID CMD ARGUMENTS.

C:\Documents and Settings\avp\src\hashcode>a xaxa
Enter a text:
12345
zxcv
^Z^Z
Output is complete!
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .

C:\Documents and Settings\avp\src\hashcode>type xaxa
12345
zxcv

C:\Documents and Settings\avp\src\hashcode>
```

Ваш код как-то работает.

**Обновление 2**

[[[[[[[[@dbs1024](/users/20373/dbs1024)](/users/20373/dbs1024)](/users/20373/dbs1024)](/users/20373/dbs1024)](/users/20373/dbs1024)](/users/20373/dbs1024)](/users/20373/dbs1024)](/users/20373/dbs1024), для форматирования кода (результатов запуска) в комментариях просто отделите форматруемый текст от остального пустыми стороками **и перед каждой стокой введите 4 пробела**.

Например (дальше пустая строка)

```
а это текст
с 4 пробелами 
перед каждой строкой
дальше опять пустая строка...
```

и снова текст комментария.

--

А у Вас `a.txt`, создаваемый программой, пустой?

--

Вообще, лучше учиться С/C++ в Linux (можно под виртуалкой). Потом, если захотите (или очень понадобится) освоите и винду.

**Обновление 3**

[[[[[[[[@dbs1024](/users/20373/dbs1024)](/users/20373/dbs1024)](/users/20373/dbs1024)](/users/20373/dbs1024)](/users/20373/dbs1024)](/users/20373/dbs1024)](/users/20373/dbs1024)](/users/20373/dbs1024), попробуйте добавить

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main ...
{
   using namespace std;

   char wd[1024];
   getcwd(wd, 1024);
   cout << "WD = [" << wd << "]\n";
```

в начало программы. В напечатанном оглавлении и ищите Ваш `a.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

[[@dbs1024](/users/20373/dbs1024)](/users/20373/dbs1024): то есть как это не создаётся? А если указать **полный** путь к файлу? Думаю, просто создаётся в неожиданном месте.

Comment: ДА! Создалось! Спасибо большое Вам за помощь